# Bringing all the rows from left join in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join

Here are two tables, reseller and domain_name, I want all the resellers against the domain_name.extensions they have(even if extension count is zero).

Problem is that this query is returning only those resellers whose extension count is not null

```
SELECT row_number() over (order by 1) as id, *, 123 as total FROM crosstab(
$$

    select domain_name.invoicing_party , domain_name.extension_id, count(*) as total  
    from reseller LEFT JOIN domain_name
    ON domain_name.invoicing_party_id = reseller.id

    where domain_name.registration_date::date = '2015-05-25'

    group by extension_id,invoicing_party
    order by  invoicing_party, extension_id

$$,

$$ SELECT m FROM generate_series(1,9) m $$
            ) AS (
                 invoicing_party varchar,  "com" varchar, "my" varchar, "idn" varchar, "net" varchar, 
                 "org" varchar, "edu" varchar, "mil" varchar, "gov" varchar, "name" varchar
            ) ;
```

Any help would of great value.

**Edit 1**

Even if I remove the where clause, even then I am getting only those resellers who have some domain extensions.

Comment: From which table does the column `registration_date` come from? (it's good coding style to always qualify your columns in a query with more than one table - then this kind of question is unnecessary)

Comment: It's domain_name.registration_date, I will make the edit.

Comment: Then move the condition from the `where` to the `on` clause. Having a `where` condition on the outer joined table effectively turns the outer join into an inner join.

Comment: See here for example: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13570612/330315

Comment: I have tried it, but it still did not bring all the resellers, one reseller having a null for count did not appear in the result set.

I might have to cater the null condition separately in the query.